# How to find off-screen ListView child in widget tests?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

When displaying multiple children in a ListView, if a child is off-screen it can't be found by a widget test. Here's a full example:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Test()));
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 600,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Text("Find me!"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

main_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_app/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets("Find text", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final testableWidget = App();

    await tester.pumpWidget(testableWidget);

    expect(find.text("Find me!"), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

This test fails, however if I change the height of the `Container` in main.dart to `599` it works.

Anyone know why this happens? Is it a bug? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tests should behave as your app would do, otherwise, your tests become useless (since you're not testing the real behavior).
As such, this is not a bug.

You have to manually scroll the `ListView` inside your tests to make it load more widgets.

This can be done using `tester`:

```
final gesture = await tester.startGesture(Offset.zero /* THe position of your listview */ );
// Manual scroll
await gesture.moveBy(const Offset(0, 100));

await tester.pump(); // flush the widget tree
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, you can also drag a widget that is in the list view: `await tester.drag(find.byType(Container), Offset(0.0, -200));
    await tester.pump();`

Answer (score 9):

Setting `skipOffstate` to `false` in your Finder is an approach. Try this:

```dart
expect(find.text("Find me!", skipOffstage: false), findsOneWidget);
```

Comment: Suggest to edit: I think that *skipOffstate* is not a parameter anymore of *ensureVisible* method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable/ensureVisible.html

Comment: That `skipOffstage` simplified so many of my tests :D - love it!

Answer (score 4):

`dragUntilVisible` helps to scroll Listview or SingleChildScrollView to scroll till the expected widget is visible

```
     final expectedWidget = find.byText("Find me!");

      await tester.dragUntilVisible(
          expectedWidget, // what you want to find
          find.byType(ListView),
          // widget you want to scroll
          const Offset(0, 500), // delta to move
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to pay attention in the "Cartesian plane" of your screen/dragging movement.

Let me explain:

1. You should use:
   await tester.drag(keyCartItemProduct1, Offset(-500.0, 0.0));
2. However, your "Offset" Command, must obey the same "Cartesian direction" than your Dragging.

2.1) Therefore: (The command Offset uses Cartesian 'directions') - lets see:
a) Left Dragging: Offset(-500.0, 0.0)
b) Right Dragging: Offset(+500.0, 0.0)
c) Up Dragging: Offset(0.0, +500.0)
d) Down Dragging: Offset(0.0, -500.0)

Answer (score 0):

try this code with skipOffstage set to false, it works fine.

```
testWidgets('Find widget off of screen', (WidgetTester tester) async {

await tester.pumpWidget(yourScreen);
expect(find.byKey(const Key('widgetname'), skipOffstage: false), findsOneWidget); });
```